# JQuery Slide out animation isn't functioning

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make a div slide out when next is clicked, and another one to slide in to replace it. The code works without the animation (when it is just `.hide()`). Can anyone tell me why it doesn't work?

Can elements with `display: flex` not working with slide in and out Jquery calls? Or?

```js
$("#next").click(function() {
    var current = $(".inner:visible");
    current.hide("slide", { direction: "left" }, 1000)

    var next = current.next(".inner");

    if(next.length == 0)
        next = current.siblings().filter(":first")
    next.css("display", "flex");
    });
```

```css
#container {
  height: 90%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.inner {
  display: none;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: row;
  height: 100%;
  width: 95%;
}

.inner:first-of-type {
  display: flex;
}

.content {
  width: 50%;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p id="next">next</p>

<div id="container">
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="content">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="content">
      <p>Donec cursus convallis malesuada. Suspendisse potenti. In tempus aliquam tempus. Curabitur aliquet porta neque, eu feugiat mauris egestas et. Mauris ut dui ut est semper ullamcorper vitae eget turpis.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Without the problematic animation:

```js
$("#next").click(function() {
    var current = $(".inner:visible");
    current.fadeOut(1000);

    var next = current.next(".inner");

    if(next.length == 0)
        next = current.siblings().filter(":first")
    next.css("display", "flex");
    next.fadeIn(1500);
    });
```

```css
#container {
  height: 90%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.inner {
  display: none;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: row;
  height: 100%;
  width: 95%;
}

.inner:first-of-type {
  display: flex;
}

.content {
  width: 50%;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p id="next">next</p>

<div id="container">
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="content">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="content">
      <p>Donec cursus convallis malesuada. Suspendisse potenti. In tempus aliquam tempus. Curabitur aliquet porta neque, eu feugiat mauris egestas et. Mauris ut dui ut est semper ullamcorper vitae eget turpis.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you fix up your snippet so that it runs without errors in the console?

Comment: Hmm, that's strange. It's working on my browser? The first animation works, but not the slide in for the following element? @cale_b

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be quite a simple problem there.
Just include easing from jQuery UI and everything should work.
https://jqueryui.com/easing/

Comment: Hmm, I don't think it is

Comment: Conceptually, this answer may be correct.  What would be _better_ is to copy the snippet from the question into your answer, include the library, and show that it works....

Comment: @skeefee use a code snippet instead of linking to an external site. Edit your answer and click the paper icon with `<>` in it.

Answer (score 0):

Addind the jquery-ui cdn seems to be working. Make sure you add jquery-ui library after jquery only.

```js
$("#next").click(function() {
    var current = $(".inner:visible");
    current.fadeOut(1000);

    var next = current.next(".inner");

    if(next.length == 0)
        next = current.siblings().filter(":first")
    next.css("display", "flex");
    next.fadeIn(1500);
    });
```

```css
#container {
  height: 90%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.inner {
  display: none;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: row;
  height: 100%;
  width: 95%;
}

.inner:first-of-type {
  display: flex;
}

.content {
  width: 50%;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-eGE6blurk5sHj+rmkfsGYeKyZx3M4bG+ZlFyA7Kns7E="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<p id="next">next</p>

<div id="container">
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="content">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="content">
      <p>Donec cursus convallis malesuada. Suspendisse potenti. In tempus aliquam tempus. Curabitur aliquet porta neque, eu feugiat mauris egestas et. Mauris ut dui ut est semper ullamcorper vitae eget turpis.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but that is exactly like the very last code snippet I posted?

Comment: the difference is the 2nd script tag they added in the html portion

Comment: Yup, I added the jquery-ui library and your animation works fine. Am I getting something wrong here or you are trying to ask something else?